# Godunov splitting convergence research

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis

The approximation of Godunov splitting on certain differential equations is known to be first order accurate. In 2011, a paper has also shown that it is first order accurate for nonlinear ordinary differential equations of the form $u' = B(u)+ku$ where $B$ is quadratic, and also for 1-dimensional KdV equation.

Does proving the first order convergence of Godunov splitting for other types of nonlinear ODE considered as not a significant research or novelty? If so, may I get the references?